# How can I get Instagram public profile information?

Tags: javascript, api, instagram

I need to get the follower and follower numbers of the profile to which the request will be sent, before sending a follow request in the chrome extension I am coding.

However, since I have to get the information of dozens of profiles in a minute, the service offered by Instagram blocks me. I have reviewed all the methods on this platform. Instagram graph api is limited to 200 requests per hour.

However, this plugin is a plugin that is used by dozens of people and needs to pull data very often.

https://www.instagram.com/test/?__a=1

Such apis where instagram presents profile data as json are blocking me after 10-15 requests and please wait a few minutes before trying again. gives the error. When I pull the page source with the back end, I cannot access the information because Instagram does not bring profile data from the source.

On the back end, I'm working with .net core mvc. Can anyone help me how to get public data like number of followers without any limitations?

Comment: The rate limit is the rate limit; not sure what kind of information you're looking for.

Comment: I'm pretty sure what kind of information I'm looking for. Instagram limits xhr requests and redirects to login page. I need to get follower count, follow count and post count of any profile with XHR. I need an api that will handle dozens of XHR requests per minute. I can write it myself, but I can't access this information because Instagram fetches profile data later. APIs also have xhr request limit. I need a way.

Comment: So you're basically asking how to bypass the IG rate limits?

Comment: It doesn't matter if you only have instagram apis. I need to withdraw public profile information without any withdrawal limit. I need to do this with the back end or xhr request. I need a system where I can get 10 profile information per second by any means. I'm in a very difficult situation, I can't find any way out. Can you please help?